# Advantage of Reselect over container component

Tags: reactjs, redux, components, containers, reselect

https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data describes how to use *reselect createSelector()* to avoid unnecessary updates when a component depends on properties that are computed values.

An alternative seems to be to move the necessary computations into a (hopefully) lightweight container component that is connected to the store instead. In this case *mapStateToProps()* would return references to the store and *connect()* would not trigger an update of the container component unless the relevant values in the store has changed:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        visibilityFilter: state.visibilityFilter,
        todos: state.todos,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onTodoClick: id => {
            dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
        }
    }
}

const connected = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
    switch (filter) {
        case 'SHOW_ALL':
            return todos
        case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
            return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
        case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
            return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connected((props) => {
    return <TodoList 
        todos={getVisibleTodos(props.todos, props.visibilityFilter)}
        onTodoClick={props.onTodoClick} 
    />
})

export default VisibleTodoList
```

Are there any reasons for preferring *reselect* over a connected container component? I don't find (m)any examples discussing the above approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you need to use `getVisibleTodos` in more than one container?

Selectors decouple your containers from the store. When the store shape changes, you only need to update selectors to get the containers in working order.

[For this reason, some would advocate placing selectors alongside the reducers.](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-colocating-selectors-with-reducers)

Selectors are also useful during testing, allowing you to make assertions in terms of domain logic rather than storage logic. This makes tests less brittle.

It's useful to think of the selectors and actions as two halves of your public store API, and everything else as implementation details that are prone to change.

Comment: I agree to the points about testing and decoupling. With regards to reusable selectors I think [this example](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data#containers-visibletodolist-js-3) shows how things get a bit out of hand (makeGetVisibleTodos and makeMapStateToProps). A container component is quite straight forward. Anyway, this is an opinionated discussion, and I'm sure that as I get more experience with these libraries the advantages will get clearer to me. Thanks for answering my first overflow question!

Answer (score 0):

Also, for many simple cases (like your filtering example) you might want to choose a more humble memoizer function over the more ceremonious setup for `createSelector()`:

```
const selectVisibleTodos = memoize(getVisibleTodos)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todos: selectVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter),
})
```

vs

```
const selectVisibleTodos = createSelector(
    (state) => state.todos,
    (state) => state.visibilityFilter,
    getVisibleTodos
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todos: selectVisibleTodos(state),
})
```

**Pros:**

- More concise code
- Faster than `createSelector` (Less internal overhead)

**Cons:**

- Less separation between `mapSateToProps` and the shape of the redux `state`

I personally tend to keep both `createSelector` and a `memoize` function at hand, and choose between them on a case by case basis.